# What Are Twitter API Get trends limits?

Tags: api, twitter

I am working on an application that will be making multiple requests daily of current trending topics from every location at any time. But, before i continue working on this, I would like to know if there is a limit in making those requests to Twitter in terms of the number of queries i can make, and if there is, is there any way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter has a well-definied API rate limiting policy. You can read all about it here:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1

You can get around these limits by implementing a token sharing hack - see this question for one specific approach: [Using Twitter Access Tokens interchangeably (ie. use 1 user's token for another user)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487996/using-twitter-access-tokens-interchangeably-ie-use-1-users-token-for-another/16034482#16034482)

Answer (score 0):

Current limits are 75 / 15-minutes
[reference](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/trends/trends-for-location/api-reference/get-trends-place)